# How to be able to have a two line text on Button content WPF ? And be able to click on text and activate Button1_click

Tags: c#, wpf

The code is shown below. When I try to click on the middle of the button you are actually clicking the TextBlock and not triggering the Button2_click event. Only if you click outside of the TextBlock and still inside of the Button it would trigger the event.

What is the right way of having a two line text inside the content of the Button.I'm a new on StackOverFlow so I don't have enough reputation to add a picture. Please some Help with this question. Thanks for the Help in Advance.

```
<Button Content="" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,136,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="202" />
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Padding="2" Margin="80,152,0,135" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="181" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF8787DB" FontWeight="Bold"> Calculate CTR Losses<LineBreak></LineBreak> (From FTD Data)</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `TextBlock` inside your button:

```xml
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,136,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TextBlock Padding="2" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF8787DB" FontWeight="Bold">
        Calculate CTR Losses
        <LineBreak />
        (From FTD Data)
     </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

This will implicitly set `Button.Content`, it's an equivalent of:

```xml
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,136,0,0" Name="Button2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Padding="2" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Foreground="#FF8787DB" FontWeight="Bold">
            Calculate CTR Losses
            <LineBreak />
            (From FTD Data)
        </TextBlock>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Your original code overlays the `TextBlock` over the button, so both of these elements aren't related.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that was fast. I am doing exactly what you told me. But it is showing no text on the TextBlock. Any Ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's right, I didn't notice the attributes at first... @omachu23 I think you can even remove more attributes, both on the text block and the button (see updated answer)

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks For the help Lucas. I would give you a vote up but I don't even have 15 reputation :(

Comment: @omachu23 No worries :) Welcome to SO btw and don't worry about the upvote, this is a quickly unlocked privilege